# Terraform plan command giving permission denied error

Tags: terraform, digital-ocean

I am trying to create a simple terraform project with Digital Ocean provider. I am following this tutorial:

[terraform sample project tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-terraform-with-digitalocean)

Now when I try to run terraform plan command, I am getting following error:

```
Error: digitalocean_droplet.www-1: 1 error(s) occurred:

* digitalocean_droplet.www-1: file: open /home/najmul/.ssh/id_rsa: permission denied in:

${file(var.pvt_key)}
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the permissions on `/home/najmul/.ssh/id_rsa`? Are you able to read it with the user that is running Terraform?

Comment: 600 (-rw-------) @ydaetskcoR and cat command is showing the contents.

Comment: Is key own by the user executing terraform?

Comment: @victorm yes. I checked viewing id_rsa properties -> Permissions

Comment: Can you post the results from "ls -la /home/najmul/.ssh/id_rsa"

Comment: @victorm -rw------- 1 najmul najmul 1679 Jun 21  2018 /home/najmul/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: Make sure the SSH Agent is running : eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

Comment: Thanks, problem is solved when I moved to latest version. I was in 0.11.11